# How to do statistics with mongoose in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, statistics

What is the best way to get statistics from documents in a mongodb:
Questions like: How many posts (documents in mongo) did a user create by month/quarter? Or in which categories did this user post? And if one post had more than one category in an array how would you count those elegantly?
Are there shortcut functions to sums/mean/sd?
What is the best way to handle this kind of data and is there some kind of datascience package like pandas in python oder R like dataframes in node?